# i18n between Symfony 1.4 and Wordpress 3

Tags: wordpress, internationalization, symfony-1.4

i'm building a web with a frontend based on wordpress and a private area based on symfony. The web have several languages, to wordpress i use qtranslate and i want to take the language selected in wordpress to change the culture in the symfony part. Any ideas?

Sorry for my english :-/

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use i18n in Symfony the culture can be switched automatically when you change the "magic" parameter `sf_culture` during request (using GET or POST). If this not enough you can switch the culture in an action by calling

```
$this->getUser()->setCulture($culture);
```

You can for example keep the current Wordpress culture in a cookie and read the cookie from your Sf backend. You can either change the culture in each action, or create a filter that will check if the Wordpress culture has changed and change it if needed.